# Unknown label type: (array([1, 1, ... ,1], dtype=object),)

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, neural-network

i have built a dict.keys() as follow, with their shape below

```
dict_keys(['Train_Input', 'Test_Input', 'Train_Target', 'Test_Target', 'Train_TargetName', 'Test_TargetName'])
           (240, 7200)     (60, 7200)      (240,)          (60,)             (240,)               (60,)
```

and then i use sciki-learn MLP to Train

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
import numpy as np
import pickle

X_train = Input_Data['Train_Input']
X_test = Input_Data['Test_Input']
Y_train = Input_Data['Train_Target']
Y_test = Input_Data['Test_Target']

mlp = MLPClassifier(solver='sgd', activation='relu',alpha=1e-4,
                    hidden_layer_sizes=(8,8), random_state=1,
                    max_iter=10, verbose=10, learning_rate_init=0.001)

mlp.fit(X_train, Y_train)

print(mlp.score(X_test, Y_test))
print(mlp.n_layers_)
print(mlp.n_iter_)
print(mlp.loss_)
print(mlp.out_activation_)
```

it has a error:

```
Unknown label type: (array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  dtype=object),)
```

i have checked their types

```
print(type(X_train))
print(type(Y_train))
print(type(X_test))
print(type(Y_test))

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

how can i solve it? which `np.dtype` should i Change Y?

Comment: Change your `Y_train` and `Y_test` dtypes to anything other than object. Strings, or ints should work.

Comment: i have tried this y=y.astype('int'), but it's the same Problem.

Comment: Where is `y` in your shown code? Have you tried `Y_train = Y_train.astype('int')` ?

Comment: i have also tried this : Y_train = Y_train.tostring(), with error: dtype='|S1920') cannot be considered a valid collection.

Comment: yes, i instead Y_train, Y_test to y